# How do I resolve persistent inactive billing state in Google Cloud [Compute Engine] and restore paused VM instances?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

I recently used up all my $300 free credits in Google Cloud compute engine and all my VM's got paused because one of them went beyond the free credit boundaries. I thought Google cloud would automatically start charging my billing account but that never happened even though I upgraded my account. Whenever I try to manually restart the vm, I get this notification:

> Project ***your-project-id*** cannot accept requests to start while in an
>   inactive billing state. Billing state may take several minutes to
>   update.

It's been 3 days and I'm still not able to get my billing account to start charging from my credit card (all details of the card are valid).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating a new billing account, paying the extra amount owed into that new account and reassigning the project to the new billing account. 
Everything seems fine now and I'm able to startup my vm instances